# Faster processing of nested objects in Ruby/RoR

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, parallel-processing, sitemap

I have to create an array that can contain all possible object combinations(each object can contain more than 10k records for example stations). I wrote three objects below, but the actual code contains 8 objects (not 3).

The problem with my code is that it is very slow and takes hours to complete. I also tried to use find_each and parallel, but I couldn't make use of it in the nested each loop. I was wondering if someone knew a way to make my code work quicker.

```rb
target_objects = %w[prefecture city station].each_with_object([]) do |obj_name, arr|
  arr << obj_name.classify.constantize.all
end
test = []
target_objects.each.with_index do |objects, index|
  objects.each do |first_obj|
    test << first_obj
    target_objects[(index + 1)..-1]&.each&.with_index(index + 1) do |second_objects, second_objects_index|
      second_objects.each do |second_obj|
        test << [first_obj, second_obj]
        target_objects[second_objects_index + 1..-1]&.each&.with_index(second_objects_index + 1) do |third_objects, third_objects_index|
          third_objects.each do |third_obj|
            test << [first_obj, second_obj, third_obj]
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: First question to ask yourself is if this is something that should be done in the database with something like a view. Processing huge amounts of records in Ruby will not scale anyways and will be slow no matter what.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I need to create an array of objects to create my sitemap using the existing method of creating sitemap urls. So I guess there is no other way and just accept that it will be slow.

Comment: You are saying you have more than 10k records in the tables and want to find all possible combinations 8 levels deep? When I get you right then there are about 10000**8 combinations. More than a Nonillion. that probably doesn't fit into memory. This sounds like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/284887) to me. Can you please elaborate on why you want to do that and what you try to archive?

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I know that there are too many combinations and using too many memories even if it is a batch processing. But I need to use an existing method that is only able to create permalinks from objects for the sitemap(I’m unable to change any logic of the method).  That is why I thought that I only have a choice to create all possible combinations in an array and then pass it to the method.

Answer (score 0):

10k records..
Use Enumerator.

```
(1..target_objects.size).flat_map{|size| target_objects.combination(size) }
```